# How to make wordpress mu work with sqlite

Tags: wordpress, sqlite, wpmu

Does [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdo-for-wordpress/) work with wpmu? If not, what alternatives exist for wpmu?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Wordpress MU with SQLite, this article might interest you : [converting standard wordpress into a SQLite powered multi user blogging platform](http://hasin.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/converting-standard-wordpress-into-a-sqlite-powered-multi-user-blogging-platform/)

It refers to the plugin you linked to, and adds some explanations -- quoting the introduction :

> WPMU (wordpress mu or multi-user) is
>   another version of wordpress which
>   uses the core wp with some
>   modifications and convert any single
>   user wordpress blog into a multi user
>   blogging platform. **in this blog post
>   i will show you how you can convert a
>   general installation of wordpress into
>   multi user blogging platform** (like
>   WPMU, but fully featured) and take
>   advantage of SQLite :) – so let the
>   fun begin.

ie, it doesn't seem to be based on Wordpress MU -- but seems to achieve the same kind of functionnalities...

Comment: i'm searching for something for wpmu

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a working working website and would like to migrate your MySQL database to SQLite, you might want to read this article:

http://livecode.byu.edu/database/mysql-sqliteExport.php

In short, the article explains how to export your Wordpress database as SQL from PHPMyAdmin. Once you have an SQL file you open the Terminal and run sqlite.

You will:

1. Create an sqlite file in your computer
2. Read the SQL file you got from PHPMyAdmin
3. Add the sqlite file to your Wordpress as explained in the link below.

http://hasin.me/2009/09/22/converting-standard-wordpress-into-a-sqlite-powered-multi-user-blogging-platform/

The only caveat, is that SQLite does not support most of the field types use in MySQL, so you will have to replace those unsupported fields with the SQLite equivalents.

Here are the fields that I replaced in my project:

- Replace int(n) and bigint(n) with INTEGER
- Replace timestamp and datetime with TEXT
- Replace varchar(n) with TEXT
- Replace varchar(n) with TEXT
- Replace (tinytext|longtext) with TEXT
- Replace CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
- Replace COLLATE with nothing
- Add PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT to id fields (manually) —except for table 'wp_term_relationships'
- Remove all ALTER statement (there are not valid in sqlite)

I did exported to SQL files from PHPMyAdmin, one for the data structure —so I could verify that the tabled were created, and another one for the data. If you get any error while reading the SQL files, just open them, fix them, and read the files again.